# WCF - Catching faults on the server and returning custom types instead

Tags: wcf, exception

We are trying to figure out a way to modify WCF service behavior to catch all exceptions and instead of returning faults to the client, it will populate a custom return object with exception data and return that. So far, we haven't had much luck. I found this example: [Catching custom faults](http://blog.ngommans.ca/index.php?/archives/33-Handling-custom-errors-in-WCF.html)

However, it doesn't return custom types as we would like it to. What other options are there?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "custom return object"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have an interoperable and "by-the-standard" service, you should **always** return `FaultException<T>` SOAP faults from your service to the client.

Since that type takes a generic `<T>`, you can basically put anything into that type there to report back your errors. That type needs to be decorated with a [DataContract], and its members that need to be passed back with [DataMember] attributes.

```
[DataContract]
public class MyErrorInfo
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

When you catch those execptions on the service side and return a `FaultException<MyErrorInfo>` (or whatever you'll end up calling your error class), you also need to decorate your operations with a

```
[FaultContract(typeof(MyErrorInfo))]
[OperationContract]
public SomeType SomeMethodCall(SomeType parameter);
```

so that your clients will be able to catch the `FaultException<MyErrorInfo>` and handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I referred to this article in another answer, but it may help you as well..
[WCF Exception Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979010/wcf-exception-handling/3979662#3979662)

the article is [Simplifying WCF: Using Exceptions as Faults](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/07/simplifying-wcf-using-exceptions-as-faults/)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [blog post on this exact topic](https://vikingerik.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/pro-tip-return-same-object-for-wcf-services/) after we encountered this in our own project. Basically, we chose to return the same object type so we can attach a single listener delegate to all events to [globally handle certain errors](https://vikingerik.wordpress.com/2010/10/06/dynamic-delegates/) (like a user losing the permissions to an org.)

I hadn't thought of using FaultException but I will examine how we might do that. This design was WCF Service (.NET 3.5) running inside SharePoint 2007 and consumed by Silverlight 4.