# WCF client creation issue

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, visual-studio-2010, iis-7

I am using VS2010 + C# + .Net 4.0 + IIS 7.0 + WCF. When I create a WCF client object instance in below code, I find "check point 1" is logged, but "check point 2" is not logged. But no exception is thrown (I catch exception in the whole block of code, and "check point 3" is not output).

Any ideas how to debug further to see issues in WCF client proxy creation? What are the normal issues in WCF client proxy creation (I think the creation just need to create a local memory object to represent the WCF client object instance, no need to really communicate to remote WCF service, so should not fail normally, please correct me if I am wrong)? Maybe some configuration errors?

BtW: the code below is in a WCF service (WCF server end, running/hosted in IIS 7.0) to call another remote WCF service.

```
try
{
    MyLogger.Write("check point 1 " );
    Foo.CustomerInfo ci = new Foo.CustomerInfo();
    MyLogger.Write("check point 2");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MyLogger.Write("check point 3");
    return;
}
```

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

Few ideas:

- Try putting logging in Foo.CustomerInfo() constructor
- Try using [end to end tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738749.aspx) with Service Trace Viewer (usually in NETFX 4.0 Tools\SvcTraceViewer.exe).
- Make sure you have you service return exception details in faults so client can "see" them (e.g. serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true")
- If you autogenerated client proxy, you can still edit it and add logging in the partial class of client proxy

Comment: Thanks zam6ak! "Make sure you have you service return exception details in faults so client can "see" them" -- you mean how to modify my class? Do you mean modify the class which is calling remote WCF service Foo.CustomerInfo, or you mean modify class which implements remote WCF? Appreciate if you could provide more details.

Comment: @George2 Take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979010/wcf-exception-handling/3979662#3979662. If your service generates any faults you client can catch them using FaultException (if it is untyped). However, the client won't be able to show the details of the exception until you setincludeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" in the service behavior (in the service configuration itself, not client side).